# Victory-native give element type is invalid error

Tags: react-native, victory-native

I want to add a bar chart on my app using victory-native library, I tried the getting started guide as seen below and got this error

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

I tried deleting node_modules and yarn.lock then do `yarn install` but it still gives the error, if I remove the victory component code (ex. just add view and random text) it will show up without an error

My code

```js
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import { VictoryBar, VictoryChart } from "victory-native";

export default function Homepage() {
  const data = [
    { quarter: 1, earnings: 13000 },
    { quarter: 2, earnings: 16500 },
    { quarter: 3, earnings: 14250 },
    { quarter: 4, earnings: 19000 },
  ];
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <VictoryChart width={350}>
        <VictoryBar data={data} x="quarter" y="earnings" />
      </VictoryChart>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#f5fcff",
  },
});
```

Dependencies

```js
"expo": "~49.0.15",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.72.6",
"@shopify/react-native-skia": "0.1.196",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
"react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
"victory-native": "^40.0.2",
```